# Interruption in waveguides

Tags: optics, waveguide, photonics, lithography, modulator

I want to fabricate a PE waveguide.I deposited a layer of aluminum with a thickness of 180 nm on Lithium niobate.I lithographed the design of the waveguide,After developing photoresist and etching the aluminum, the waveguide was interrupted(disconnect) in some parts.in fact aluminum doesn't remove from some places. What is the reason? Could it be because of the quality of the aluminum or not related? In addition,My mask(used in lithography process) is ok.

Comment: I feel stupid that I don't understand this, but are you sure you're in the right community now? If waveguides are Electrical Engineering, please forgive me.

Comment: @MiNiMe That's all right, yes it's in the micro and nano electronic devices fied.

Comment: I have learned something today, even though I don't understand. I'm confident you will get good answers here.

Comment: @MiNiMe Waveguides are used for a highly specialized subfield of EE: microwave engineering.

Comment: @Hearth and photonics! And technical acoustics!

Comment: we only know what you tell us. How are we to diagnose your depostion/lithography process? You're the only one sitting in front of your substrate, you need to describe it in *way* more detail, and probably take photos, and explain what you think the possible sources of problems were!

Comment: There may be knowledgeable people here, but keep in mind most are practicing or amateur EEs, not so many microelectronics. These questions seem extremely narrow and specific to your process, and therefore would be best addressed to the fab, or whoever is responsible for it e.g. department head, advisor, manager, etc. While the application may be electronic, the process is intimately chemical or physical, and you might have better input from those stacks instead -- but you will need to describe your situation in no less detail.

Comment: @TimWilliams sad but true! I wish there was more people that know their way around solid state electronics and photonics on here – both not my strongest subjects during my EE studies backintehday, but undeniably central EE topics today; and when it comes to the second E in E, they should probably be much more prominent than [tag:555] questions or "how do I switch from battery to USB when available; I haven't researched much" type questions…

Comment: I downvote the question because it seems to be extremely narrow (not likely to benefit the community) and too non-specific. To start with, what is PE? Photoelectric, polyethylene, protective earth? Please make your question easy to read, so we don't need to guess. Then, "What is the reason? My mask is OK" does not provide any details to help diagnose. Also I feel "optics" (due to which I am reading it) is an irrelevant tag here, since the question is about the fabrication process rather than an optical device or effect.

Comment: @texnic well, I wouldn't weigh the [tag:optics] tag against OP, since the choice of tags here is quite limited. "Photonic-device" simply doesn't exist. So, yeah, this is about optics, because that is how you know your waveguide isn't functioning. But I do agree, there needs to be a description of error. I do **not** agree about the narrowness: we encourage people to ask narrow questions. Heck, "how to use a 555 to generate a 50% duty cycle square wave" is much narrower than "How do I make this general type of optical waveguide work";and how many questions of the former type do we have on here?

Comment: @texnic The aim is NOT to beneft this community pser se. It is to benefit the greter electronics community. (That's in the oiginal discussiom documents from years ago). (Benefit to this community is a bonu.  The more narrow superb Q&As we have the better. They do not impact the day to day humdrum ones negatively and they overall bring  high capability people to the site. || You can downvote as you choose BUT I suggest upvoting would be in order :-).